# Creating a big url

Tags: django, url, sorting, view, filtering

There are references:
sort1, sort2
filter1, filter2

We click on a sort1 and have a new url like: `www.example.com?sort=1`

Then we click on filter1 and we must have: `www.example.com?sort=1&filter=1`

Then we click on filter2 and we must have: `www.example.com?sort=1&filter=2`

and etc...

how can i do this, add more parametrs? my parameters change each other and always only one.

Comment: look at using forms, with action=`GET` instead of `POST`

Comment: can you give me some example or link to documentation/tutorial ?

Comment: @Arti: Read up the form handling example - [http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07.html](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter07.html)

Answer (score 1):

Query parameters like your `sort` and `filter` will be passed to your `/` route through `GET` variable.  So your URLconf looks like:

**urls.py**

```
...
url(r'^/$',
    sorter
),
```

Note that you don't put your `GET` parameters in your URLconf.  Instead, they are parsed in key-value fashion and put in an [HTTPRequst](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects) object, which gets passed to your view. Your view looks like:

**views.py**

```
def sorter(request):
   ...
```

and in this view, you can access your `GET` parameters through `request.GET`.  For example, you might use `request.GET['sort']` to get the value of the `sort` parameter.  Because parameters are key/value pairs, you can have essentially as many as you want in any order, and it's up to the logic of the view to put them into use.  You might want to start at [Part 4 of the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial04/) for an example of request processing, noting that URL query parameters are passed in `request.GET` instead of `request.POST`.

Answer (score 0):

try some of the examples in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs), replacing `POST` with `GET` in templates and views and see what happens